# Hadoop is it recommended only for distributed env?

Tags: database, hadoop

I have a database whose size could go upto 1TB in a month. If I do a query directly, its taking a long time. So I was thinking of using Hadoop on top of the Database - most of the time my query would involve searching entire database. My database instance would be either 1 or 2, not more than that. After a while we purge the database.
     So can we use hadoop framework since it helps processing large amount of data?

Comment: Hadoop isn't something you put "on top" of a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is not "something you query" but you can use it to process a large amount of data and create a search index which you then load into a system you *can* query.

You can also look into [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) if you want a store for big data.  In addition to HBase there are a number of other key-value or non-relational (NoSQL) stores that work well with large data.

A proper answer depends on the kind of query you are running.  Are you always running a specific query?  If so, then a key-value store works well; just choose the right keys.  If your query *needs to search the entire database* as you say, and you only make one query every hour or two, then yes, in principle, you could write a simple "query" in Hive that will read from your HDFS store.

Note that querying in Hive only saves you time versus an RDBMS or a simple `grep` when you have a lot of data and access to a decent-sized cluster.  If you only have one machine, it's a non-solution.

Comment: Thanks Ray for quick response.We have other queries for which I don't need to query entire DB except 1 query (btb this 1 query syntx remain the same and the value may change for example from '$100' to '$50')  my mongoDB size may go up to 40TB or even more but less than 100TB. So i plan to split the DB based on size. say 5 or 10TB per instance. Based on this data ..wat do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop works better on distributed system. Moreover 1TB is not big data., for this your relational database will do the job.
The real power of hadoop comes when you have to process 100 TB or more of data .. where the relational databases fail.

If look into Hbase it is fast but it is not a substitute to your MySQL or Oracle..

Comment: Thanks, Please refer to my response to Ray above and comment back.